# Help please! Error when accessing Data within a cursor returned by SQLite for android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am an android novice and have been experimenting with SQLite and Android.  I am able to get queries and use the cursor results, but I can't seem to get this the following code to work:

This is my Query statement, where queryWhere = "MyObject="1"" and DATABASE_TABLE_TOQUERY = "FavoriteObjects".  These are all okay when viewed in an SQLite database viewer and it also returns a correct result if I execute the query using my SQLite database viewer.

```
public long findObject(String[] keys, String[] values,String DATABASE_TABLE_TOQUERY){
    try {
        if(keys.length<0 || keys.length!=values.length)
            System.exit(-1);
        String queryWhere = keys[0]+"=\""+values[0]+"\"";
        for(int i=1;i<keys.length;i++) {
            queryWhere+=" AND "+keys[i]+"=\""+values[i]+"\"";
        }
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_TOQUERY, null, 
                    queryWhere, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null && mCursor.getCount()>0)
            return Long.parseLong(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID)));

    }catch (SQLException e) {
        return -1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

When I get the results after executing the query statement, Cursor mCursor has at least one row, but when I access that row using mCursor.getString(X), it throws a weird error:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

If I check mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID), I get a 0 value (which is correct). Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
mCursor.moveToNext();
```

Comment: THank you!  Could you tell me why that happened like that?  getCount() was only 1 for the cursor...

Comment: You need to moveToNext() for each row. "Move the cursor to the first row.

This method will return false if the cursor is empty." You can loop over all rows   while (c.moveToNext()) { .. use row data .. }

Comment: Call moveToFirst() at first and then moveToNext().